# Credentials for Maven server in separate file

Tags: playframework, sbt, nexus, playframework-2.5

I use a secured Maven server for dependencies of my project and got it working adding this to my build.sbt file:

`resolvers ++= Seq("scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
                  "pexxlab" at "https://nexus.pexxlab.xyz/repository/maven-snapshots/")
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "nexus.pexxlab.xyz", "username", "password")`

Now this is less than ideal in a project where I am not the only developer as I don't want my credentials in the Git Repository.

Is there a way to give it my credentials with a separate file like Maven does it?

Comment: If your dependencies are in that repo, how are those other developers going to accomplish anything if they can't download the dependencies needed to run or even compile?

Comment: They have their own credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have the credentials in your global settings (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html).

> Basic global configuration file
>
> Settings that should be applied to all projects can go in
>   ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt (or any file in ~/.sbt/0.13 with a .sbt
>   extension).